# How to upload image from mobile in rails app and carrierwave uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, file-upload, carrierwave, titanium-mobile

We have a web application in ruby on rails. Now we are developing API and an app for android and iphone. We are using titanium for mobile app. In the web application to upload file we use carrier wave. I am following same process as shown in railscast to upload files using carrierwave. My question is how can I do this in mobile app. I need idea and sample code if possible. Following is my code that works okay for the web version of the application.

Controller action

```
 def create_file
    @community_message_file = Community::MessageFile.new(params[:community_message_file])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @community_message_file.save
        format.js {}
      else
        flash.now[:error] = @community_message_file.errors.size > 0 ? ErrorUtility.validation_errors(@community_message_file.errors) :
            "Saving failed"
        format.js {}
      end
    end
  end
```

Some methods model

```
mount_uploader :file_path, MessageFileUploader

  validates :file_path, file_size: {maximum: 1.megabytes.to_i}

  def extension
    return extract_extension
  end

  def file_name
    return File.basename(self.file_path.to_s)
  end

  def image?
    file_extension = extract_extension
    return true if (file_extension == 'jpeg' || file_extension == 'jpg' || file_extension == 'png' || file_extension == 'gif')
    return false
  end

  private

  def extract_extension
    return File.extname(self.file_path.to_s).split('.').last
  end
```

And my uploader model

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  after :remove, :clear_uploader
storage :file
def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def clear_uploader
    @file = @filename = @original_filename = @cache_id = @version = @storage = nil
    model.send(:write_attribute, mounted_as, nil)
  end

def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png doc docx xls xlsx pdf zip)
  end

def image?(new_file)
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png).include?(new_file.extension.to_s)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested using the ios simulator. With a file field, mobile safari prompts the photos app to select a photo. From there how you implement it on the back end is irrelevant. The browser request will work the same as it does for desktop.